# DLL wrapper method return delay

Tags: c#, c++, dll, wrapper

A company produces a device with an ethernet connector. I have one of their devices and they gave me a .lib file and some .h files so I can connect and communicate with their device. Works fine, I'm glad.
Then the company produced a new version of their device. I also have this newer device and again they gave me some files so I can connect and communicate with it: this time a .lib file, a .dll file and some .h files.

So much for the background. Now, the problem:

I wrote a simple test application in MS Visual C++ 6.0 to see what happens, when I try to connect to the new device with the old interface: the connect() method provided (using the old .lib file) immediately returns 0 (Could not connect). Makes sense, I agree!
But, when I wrap that .lib file in a .dll file and try the same scenario again, I don't get an immediate result, it takes 42 seconds until I get the 0 result!
The wrapper works fine when I try to connect to the older device, no problem at all.

This is the first project where I have to wrap up a .lib file in a .dll file (I did that so I can use it in C#), so I don't know too much about this topic. All I know is, that I'm passing along values from the original method calls to the wrapper ... How can there be such a delay? It must happen somewhere in the Wrapping, but I have no clue. Networking shouldn't be the problem, because without wrapper I get the result immediately. Maybe something about Threading or DLLs?

I was hoping someone could enlighten me here ...

I didn't post any specific code, because I wouldn't know what is relevant here. If you need more information, please let me know!

**EDIT:**
In C# I have a class MyDLLImport:

```
class MyDLLImport
{
    [DllImport("Old_Interface_MSVC++GeneratedDLL.dll")]
    public static extern int Connect();

    [DllImport("Old_Interface_MSVC++GeneratedDLL.dll")]
    public static extern int Disconnect();

    ...
}
```

In another C# class I access these methods directly, like:

```
MyDLLImport.Connect();
```

The .lib and .h files I wrapped up in the Old_Interface_MSVC++GeneratedDLL.dll file like this:

Old_Interface_MSVC++GeneratedDLL.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Old_Interface_MSVC++GeneratedDLL_Class.h"
#include "Old_Interface_MSVC++GeneratedDLL.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
        DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
        LPVOID lpReserved
    )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

ALibClass MyDLL::client;

int MyDLL::Connect()
{
    int ret;

    ret = MyDLL::client.Connect();
    if(!ret)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not connect" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void MyDLL::Disconnect()
{
    MyDLL::client.Disconnect();
}

...

/////////////////////////////////
// exported functions

int Connect()
{
    return MyDLL::Connect();
}

void Disconnect()
{
    MyDLL::Disconnect();
}
```

Then, there is the header file for the previous .cpp file, Old_Interface_MSVC++GeneratedDLL.h:

```
#ifdef MYDLL_EXPORTS
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// added by myself to prevent export warnings
#pragma warning( disable: 4251 )

/////////////////////////////////////////////
//exported general methods
extern "C" MYDLL_API int Connect();
extern "C" MYDLL_API void Disconnect();

...
```

And finally the class header file Old_Interface_MSVC++GeneratedDLL_Class.h:

```
#include "lib_header_file.h"

class MyDLL
{
private:
    static ALibClass client;

public:
    static int Connect();
    static void Disconnect();

    ...
}
```

I hope I have added all relevant code parts. If you need more information, let me know!

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of MSVC++ compiler?  You need to determine what version of C++ the library is written against.  **Without the wrapper code we can't explaint he delay.**

Comment: USe [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) to map types to managed.

Comment: I use such an old version of MSVC++ compiler because a sample project came with the .lib and .h files. I tried a newer compiler 
(MSVC++ Studio) but after several days of fiddling with project configuration I gave up. I added some code, hope it helps. About the PInvoke: I will read into that, thx!